# Why does an apostrophe throws me an error on test attribute of xsl:when

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a scenario where i should check if the education level of an entity is equal to 'Bachelor's Degree/Undergraduate Degree' but the compiler throws me an error saying "Expected end of the expression, found 's '."

Here is my actual code:

```
        <xsl:when test="education_level='Bachelor's Degree/Undergraduate Degree'">
          <opleiding>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
              <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="'30001'"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="'Specialisation'"/>
          </opleiding>
        </xsl:when>
```

Guys help will be appreciated :) thanks in advance

Comment: Good question, +1. The code can be written correctly without using any additional variable. Also, you cannot use DOE when creating an attribute -- it will either be ignored or will cause an error to be raised.

Comment: Forgive me Dimitre. can i know what is the meaning of DOE?

Comment: @_Allan Chua: DOE = Disable Output Escaping

Comment: To output a fixed string, use `<xsl:text>30001</xsl:text>`. You don't need xsl:value-of and you certainly don't need disable-output-escaping. And for the attribute, you can just use `<opleiding id="30001">`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="s">Bachelor's Degree/Undergraduate Degree</xsl:variable>
```

and then:

```
<xsl:when test="education_level = $s">
```

Comment: Hi this worked out thanks, But you have to remove those '' inside the variable :) thanks

Comment: Is there any better way than this approach? I think this could slow down the transformation a bit?

Comment: @AllanChua: Yes, there *is* a better way: see my answer.

Comment: @AllanChua: If it's as fixed as it looks, the variable can be declared globally in the root of the stylesheet itself, which wouldn't slow it down that much. It might be marginally less efficient that encoding it directly in the `<xsl:when>` node, but it would certainly be more readable, and easier to change. You could even make it a `<xsl:param>` instead of an `<xsl:variable>`, giving you the ability to override it with a different value without changing the stylesheet, should that be useful.

Comment: @Flynn1179 you're right thanks for the help buddy this answer is best. I've already solve the problem:)

Comment: Given a processor with a half-decent optimiser, there should be no performance penalty in using this approach.

Answer (score 2):

**It is possible to specify the XPath expression in the `test` attribute without resorting at all to an additional variable and its text-node child**:

```
    <xsl:when test="education_level=&quot;Bachelor&apos;s Degree/Undergraduate Degree&quot;">
```

Here is a complete transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="education_level=&quot;Bachelor&apos;s Degree/Undergraduate Degree&quot;">
            <opleiding>
                <xsl:attribute name="id">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'30001'"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="'Specialisation'"/>
            </opleiding>
        </xsl:when>
     </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied to the following XML document**:

```
<t>
 <education_level>Bachelor's Degree/Undergraduate Degree</education_level>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<opleiding id="30001">Specialisation</opleiding>
```

**Additional Note**: You *dont* need DOE and in this particular case it will either be ignored or will produce an error -- this is because DOE is allowed only on instructions that create a text node -- not an attribute.

Comment: Dimitre Novatchev Thanks allot for the help buddy. :) but I think im already comfortable with this one because i can already changed it any time by the way thanks again for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

You need different strategies depending on whether the quote/apostrophe you need to escape is an XML attribute delimiter (the outer quotes) or an XPath string delimiter (the inner quotes).

For XML attribute delimiters, use the XML predefined entities `&quot;` and `&apos;`.

For XPath string delimiters, in XPath 2.0 you can escape them by doubling (like in SQL), for example `select="'I won''t'"`. In XPath 1.0 there's no way of escaping string delimiters, so you need a workaround like using variables, or concatenating, or switching your use of double vs single quotes. In practice I generally use variables as you have been shown.

Answer (score -1):

Escape the ' in "Bachelor's degree" - you currently have `education_level='Bachelor'` and then `s Degree/Undergraduate Degree'`.  Try `education_level='Bachelor\'s Degree/Undergraduate Degree'`

Comment: Yeah, because C# is the only language that needs to escape `'`.  I'll admit I don't know everything there is to know about XSLT, but my answer was correct in regards to escaping the `'`, it was only incorrect insofar as I escaped it wrong (using C-like syntax, because I work with Java/C usually).

Answer (score -1):

Here's the tag as you have it in your question:

```
test="education_level='Bachelor's Degree/Undergraduate Degree'"
```

I'll be the first to say that I know nothing about xslt files. XML Style sheets? I'm not sure. Regardless it's purpose, any parser would have the same problem in that you've enclosed a name/value pair as the value of a name/value pair and its causing you problems. The inner single quote (in Bachelor's) isn't being parsed as a literal quotation mark in the string, it's being parsed as the end of the value, i.e. the parser is parsing things as `test` being the first name, and it's value is the name/value pair of `education_level='Bachelor'` followed by some stuff it doesn't know what to do with: `s Degree/Undergraduate Degree '`.

In most languages, you have to escape internal quotation marks so they are seen as characters in the string and not syntactical characters representing the end of the string. Try this for the first tag:

```
<xsl:when test="education_level='Bachelor\'s Degree/Undergraduate Degree'">
```

The `\` is the escape character in most languages and should be for an xslt as well.

Comment: For the record, this works in many different languages. C#, C++, Java, VB, python. I agree with Chris Browne's comment on his own answer that the 2 of us escaped the `'` wrong, but that is the root cause of your problem.